# multithread java app ouput an strange result when click "stop" button in debug tool Netbeans

Tags: java, multithreading

I have learn about multithread in java using wait() and notify() mechanism.
But i'm very curious with output of a simple multithread java app.
*Code below:*

```
class Q {

    int n;
    boolean valueSet = false;

    synchronized int get() {
        if (!valueSet) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("InterruptedException caught");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Got: " + n);
        valueSet = false;
        notify();
        return n;
    }

    synchronized void put(int n) {
        if (valueSet) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("InterruptedException caught");
            }
        }
        this.n = n;
        valueSet = true;
        System.out.println("Put: " + n);
        notify();
    }
}

class Producer implements Runnable {

    Q q;

    Producer(Q q) {
        this.q = q;
        new Thread(this, "Producer").start();
    }

    public void run() {
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            q.put(i++);
        }
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable {

    Q q;

    Consumer(Q q) {
        this.q = q;
        new Thread(this, "Consumer").start();
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            q.get();
        }
    }
}

class PCFixed {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Q q = new Q();
        new Producer(q);
        new Consumer(q);
        System.out.println("Press Control-C to stop.");
    }
}
```

Fist, I run that app after that i click "stop" button in debug tool to stop app. And that make two "strange type output":
This is output of first time app run:

[image: Why we have two duplicate output line :***"put: 13177"***]

[image: Why we have two duplicate output line :***"got: 2713"***]
This is output of second time app run:

Why we have two ***duplicate output line*** :***"put: 13177"***

Why we have two ***duplicate output line*** :***"got: 2713"*** at another time.

That result make me confused!! Some body can help me understand this problem!!
Thank in advanced.

Comment: You should wait `while(!valueSet)` instead of `if` because an interrupt does not guarantee that `valueSet` changed. But that should not be your problem. It probably has to do with the stop button that causes some sideeffects.

Answer (score 0):

The method `Q.put(13177)` is being called twice.